# How to config .net core to consider all public method as noneAction Method except those are decorated with HttpVerb Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I have some public method in apicontroller which I want to be ignored automatically or to be considered as noneaction

```
public class CustomerOrderController : apiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public int Post([FromBody] customerOrder)
    {
        CalculateDiscount(customerOrder);
        CalculateOrderAmount(customerOrder);
        //save person
    }

    [NonAction]
    public int CalculateDiscount(CustomerOrder customerOrder)
    {
        //CalculateDiscount
    }

    [NonAction]
    public int CalculateOrderAmount(CustomerOrder customerOrder)
    {
        //CalculateOrderAmount
    }
}
```

I know that it's not a good idea to have business method in controller (I am dealing with some legacy code).

I have tried to put NonAction attribute on public business method and it worked but I want to configure it globally.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, have no chance to test this solution now, so you might need to work around it a bit, but I believe that the general direction you should take is this:

**Write extension service method that will load your controllers from assembly and change their behaviour**

It should look something like this:

```
public static void LoadControllers(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Find controllers in application
            var controllers =
                from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                from t in a.GetTypes()
                let attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ControllerAttribute), true)
                where attributes?.Length > 0 
                      && !(attributes.Contains(typeof(HttpPostAttribute))
                      || attributes.Contains(typeof(HttpGetAttribute))) // add all attributes of controllers you don't want to change
                select new {Type = t};

            var controllersList = controllers.ToList();

            // Change their behaviour and register them
            foreach (var controller in controllersList)
                services
                    .AddMvc(o => o.Filters.Add(typeof(NonActionAttribute)))
                    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
                    .AddApplicationPart(controller.Type.Assembly);
        }
```

then call this configuration from your Startup.cs.

As I said, I am not sure if this solution is working perfectly, but if you play around it a little, you should get it to work.